# validating an AWS json response on JSONLint

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, boto3

I'm trying to validate the json response from AWS's boto3 module on JSONlint validator and I'm getting an error.

Here is the code I ran:

```
import boto3
import json

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

for status in ec2.meta.client.describe_instance_status()['InstanceStatuses']:
    print(status)
```

Here is the response:

```
{u'InstanceId': 'i-xxxxxxxx', u'InstanceState': {u'Code': 16, u'Name': 'running'}, u'AvailabilityZone': 'us-xxx-west-1b', u'SystemStatus': {u'Status': 'ok', u'Details': [{u'Status': 'passed', u'Name': 'reachability'}]}, u'InstanceStatus': {u'Status': 'ok', u'Details': [{u'Status': 'passed', u'Name': 'reachability'}]}}
```

When I paste that response on JSONLint, here is the response:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1:
 {  u 'InstanceId': 'i-0
----^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'
```

I'm assuming that AWS is returning a correctly formatted JSON response, or not?

Comment: The data has already been parsed into a Python dictionary. There is no JSON for you to deal with. Why are you checking the response on JSONLint?

Comment: @AlexHall I'm a newbie and I want to understand JSON so this is not a JSON response but a python dictionary response. How do I give you credit for the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data has already been parsed into a Python dictionary, which is what you are seeing. It looks similar to JSON but it's not. There is no JSON for you to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

As Alex already mentioned, you're printing a Python dictionary, which is slightly different than JSON. For instance, the "u" prefix marks the following string as unicode.

You don't have to worry about getting invalid JSON responses since boto3 usually throws exceptions in case of AWS API errors.